# NDSolve evolution in a specific point

Tags: differential-equations

```
m = 0; n = 0; B = 0.7; W = 4;

T1[m_,n_]:= NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(m - 1)*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]]*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]], {t, 0, 1}];
T2[m_,n_]:= NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(m - 1)*LaguerreL[n - 1, m, -Log[t]]*LaguerreL[n - 1, m, -Log[t]], {t, 0, 1}];
T3[m_,n_]:= NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(m - 1)*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]]*LaguerreL[n - 1, m, -Log[t]], {t, 0, 1}];
T4[m_,n_]:= NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(m + 1)*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]]^2*Exp[-B/(f0[z])^2*(-Log[t])^m*t*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]]^2]*(-2*n*(-Log[t])^(m - 1)*t*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]]^2 +2*(m + n)*(-Log[t])^(m - 1)*t*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]]*LaguerreL[n - 1, m, -Log[t]] - (-Log[t])^m*t*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]]^2 -m*(-Log[t])^(m - 1)*t*LaguerreL[n, m, -Log[t]]^2), {t, 0, 1}];

s[m_,n_,B_,W_,z]:=NDSolve[{f0''[z] + 1/f0[z]*(f0'[z])^2 == n!/((n + m)!*(2*n + m + 1))*1/(f0[z])^3*(((n + m)!)/n!*(-2*n - m + 1) + T1[m, n]*(2*n + m)^2 + 4*T2[m, n]*(m + n)^2 - 4*T3[m, n]*(m + n)*(m + 2*n) + B*W^2*T4[m, n, B, z]), f0[0] == 1, f0'[0] == 0},f0[z], {z, 0, 10}];

f0[z_] /. s

f0[0.1]
```

My code is given above. I have some integrations T1,T2,T3,T4 and one differentiations. I want to find the result of  NDSolve at a specific value z=0.1, but I am getting some error.
Can you suggest me to how to write the code.

Comment: Please format your code (see the help). Also what error are you getting exactly? “Some error” is not descriptive enough.

Comment: I have got the result. Answer by Mr. Nasser has proved very helpful for me to get my result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful in Mathematica with spaces and multiplication

Edit: This solution works for `W=0` only.

```
m=0;n=0;B=0;W=0;

T1[m_,n_]:=NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(m-1)*LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]]*LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]],{t,0,1}];

T2[m_,n_]:=NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(m-1)*LaguerreL[n-1,m,-Log[t]]*LaguerreL[n-1,m,-Log[t]],{t,0,1}];

T3[m_,n_]:=NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(m-1)*LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]]*LaguerreL[n-1,m,-Log[t]],{t,0,1}];

T4[m_,n_]:=NIntegrate[(-Log[t])^(m+1)LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]]^2Exp[-B/(f0[z])^2*(-Log[t])^m*t*LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]]^2](-2n*(-Log[t])^(m-1)t*LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]]^2+2*(m+n)(-Log[t])^(m-1)t*LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]]LaguerreL[n-1,m,-Log[t]]-(-Log[t])^m*t*LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]]^2-m*(-Log[t])^(m-1)t*LaguerreL[n,m,-Log[t]]^2),{t,0,1}];

sol=NDSolve[{f0''[z]+1/f0[z](f0'[z])^2==n!/((n+m)!(2n+m+1))1/(f0[z])^3(((n+m)!)/n!(-2n-m+1)+T1[m,n](2n+m)^2+4T2[m,n](m+n)^2-4T3[m,n](m+n)(m+2n)+B*W^2*T4[m,n]),f0[0]==1,f0'[0]==0},f0 ,{z,0,1}]
```

[image]

```
  Plot[Evaluate[f0[z]/.sol],{z,0,1}]
```

[image]

```
  f0[0.1] /. sol

  (*  {1.00498}  *)
```

You could also use `sol = NDSolveValue[.....]` and then just use `sol[0.1]` instead.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you for everything.

Comment: But I want the result when the value of B=0.7 and W=4.

Comment: @amanbhatia  I see. There are two problems, first you call to T4 is written as `T4[m, n, B, z]` but your function `T4` is defined with only 2 arguments `T[m,n]` so you should fix the call to be `T[m,n]` so it matches. Also after doing that, there is another problem because you are using `f0[z]` inside `T4` to do numerical integration, and this is what `NDSolve` is solving for. `NIntegrate` does not like that. It worked when `W=0` since that made the whole term zero.   I do not have time now to look for workaround. Please unaccept this answer for now.

Comment: Actually when I use T4 as T4[m, n, B, z], then my problem is resolved. Now I get the value of  f0[z] at each and every value of  B and W which I want.